# Monodroid How to get the PPI of a display

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, ppi

Does anyone know any formula or any way to find the PPI of an android phone display?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this was answerd a coupple fn times here. Check the [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) class.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```